# Unzip multiple files into directory with same name

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, command-line

I have a zip archive and I want to extract only files that start with 'word' and put them into a directory 'dest_dir' under the same file name (wordxxxx.csv)
I have tried the following command:

```
unzip -p archive.zip dir1/dir2/word*.csv -d dest_dir
```

But I get this error even though I have full control permissions over dest_dir

```
Access denied
```

Should I create a loop or something?

Comment: Why do you use opion `-p  extract files to pipe, no messages` ?

Comment: that was the actual problem. I posted the good command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-p` option was the actual problem. I resolved it with:

```
unzip archive.zip dir1/dir2/word*.csv -d dest_dir
```